# How to implement styled-components SCSS editor in Monaco?

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components, monaco-editor

I have a component where user can write his own styles which are directly being injected to styled-components wrapper.

```js
const Component = styled.div`
  ${({ containerStyle = "" }) => containerStyle}
`
```

As you can see Monaco does not support top level CSS Properties without any selectors:

[image: no suggestions]

If I wrap css to selector it works fine.

[image]

**How can I make Monaco support this syntax?**

Answer (score 0):

This question touches a bigger problem than you might think. What you are after is to support a new language in Monaco. This requires an own parser, own data structures to keep the document outline in memory (for things like code completion), own syntax highlighter and so on. It's not like to switch a setting and Monaco would magically support your language/dialect.

Comment: I undestand but can I do some hacks or tricks to get this thing work. I see [the extension](https://github.com/styled-components/vscode-styled-components) which can make things work for styled components maybe I need to modify it? or can I just wrap the styles to some selector and hide them, something like `:target { // styles here }` and then hide the `:target {` and `}` rows by monaco editor.